# PHP Socket Programming : Server not accessible from outside network

Tags: php, sockets, networking, portforwarding

I am working on PHP socket programming project. In this project we are going to create a service in php socket. This socket will listen on one particular port. And client from outside network will able to communicate on that port.

Till now I am able to create server and client in php for socket programming. Now my pc is connected to LAN so I have to use port forward for connecting my pc with outside client. I forward port 2000 and all communication on that port is transfer to my pc IP address. I have netgear router n150 wireless adsl .I add all configuration on that router. I test port forwarding online at this site http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ it says port is open.

I test my code on locally (intranet), it is working fine. But when I trying to run server on my pc and client from web server which is my ipage hosting server. It throws me error  "Server Could not connect to server".

Server.php

```
<?php

// set some variables
// My LAN Ip
$host = "192.168.0.5";
$port = 2000;
// don't timeout!
set_time_limit(0);
// create socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create       socket\n");
// bind socket to port
$result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not bind to socket\n");
// start listening for connections
$result = socket_listen($socket, 3) or die("Could not set up socket  listener\n");  
$spawn = socket_accept($socket) or die("Could not accept incoming  connection\n");
// read client input
$input = socket_read($spawn, 1024) or die("Could not read input\n");
// clean up input string
$input = trim($input);
echo "Client Message : " . $input;
// reverse client input and send back
$output = strrev($input) . "\n";
socket_write($spawn, $output, strlen($output)) or die("Could not write      output\n");
// close sockets
socket_close($spawn);
socket_close($socket);
?>
```

Client.php

```
        <?php
         //my public ip
        $host = "117.223.90.191";
        // port on which I port forword
        $port = 2000;
        $message = "Hello Server";
        echo "Message To server :" . $message;
        // create socket
        $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
        // connect to server
        $result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not connect to server\n");
        // send string to server
        socket_write($socket, $message, strlen($message)) or die("Could not send data to server\n");
        // get server response
        $result = socket_read($socket, 1024) or die("Could not read server response\n");
        echo "Reply From Server  :" . $result;
        // close socket
        socket_close($socket);
        ?>
```

Any suggestion for problem. I think many will have same problem like me.

Answer (score 0):

Even if i think the problem is in the lan forwarding, try testing it with :

```
telnet 117.223.90.191 2000
```

another thing to try is to make the server listen on all interfaces

```
$host = "0.0.0.0";
```

and take a look at http://reactphp.org/